# How to traverse through this linked list to print out ages

Tags: c, linked-list

I have the following structure, and below it, a call to a function which prints the age of each member.

```
          struct details num[] = {
                  //number    //name /age /sex 
                {&num[0], "Jack", 18, male}
                {&num[1], "Jill", 23, female}
                {&num[2], "John", 43, male}
                {&num[3], "Kate", 34, female}

            }

            print_age(&num[0]);
```

Another c file containing the function:

```
           void print_age(struct details *d){
I need this function to traverse through the 'details' struct and print out the ages of
all members, i.e. 18,23,43,34
```

How can I achieve the above with the function print_age?

Comment: Looks like your teacher gave you everything you need to do the traversal. You're asking how to call `printf`?

Comment: Your variable is called `number` not `details`. `struct details` is a type. UNless I'm missing something, you don't have a linked list, you have an array of 4 structures. Also, you don't need to call `print_age` with `&number[0]`, this is redundant. Just call it with `number`

Comment: Ironically, there's not enough information in this question to provide an answer.

Comment: @PhilM I'm unsure how to go through all arrays in struct details.

Comment: I am guessing the name of the fields are `number`, `name`, `age` and `sex`? If yes, then the age is the `age` field.

Comment: @alvits Yes they are the name of the fields :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the structure is defined like this:

```
struct details {
    char name[10];
    int age;
    char sex;
};
```

To print the age all you need is to print the field `age`.
Using the definition from your question:

```
void print_age(struct details *d)
```

The implementation can be written like this:

```
void print_age(struct details *d){
    printf("%d\n", d->age);
}
```

To print all the ages, all you need is to call this function for every structure.

```
for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    print_age(num+i);
```

If you need the function to receive the whole array and traverse it, you will need to pass the number of array members to let `print_age()` know how many there are.

You should consider changing the print function to something like this:

```
void print_age(struct details *d, int nmem){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<nmem; i++)
        printf("%d\n", d->age);
}
```